# JPA with Hibernate 3.6.8.Final, PostgreSQL 9.1, SQLGrammarException - configuration issue? Weird SQL statement

Tags: hibernate, jpa, postgresql-9.1

**Edit**:
**SOLVED**
Right. I found the thing that confused me.
I use pgadmin to create tables and others database internals, checked right now: if at least one letter in the name (table name, column name, pk name, etc) is in the upper case, then pgadmin uses it in the SQL creation script as it is, using double quotes, so PostgreSQL interprets the name as it was written. If run the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE
(
  ID integer NOT NULL,
  TITLE character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT SAMPLE_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE SAMPLE
  OWNER TO postgres;_
```

it creates everything in the lower case, and the original Sample.java version works fine.

---

What is wrong here? Is this issue specific to PostgreSQL 9.1 or PostgreSQL in general, or some hibernate configuration is missing?

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence-unit name="com.sample.persistence.jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.sample.persistence.Sample</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql:sample"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Sample.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE")
public class Sample {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

**PersistenceMain.java:**

```
public class PersistenceMain {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.sample.persistence.jpa");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Sample sample = em.find(Sample.class, 1l);

        System.out.println("Sample Title: " + sample.getTitle());

        em.close();

        emf.close();
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
...
Hibernate: 
    select
        sample0_.ID as ID0_0_,
        sample0_.TITLE as TITLE0_0_ 
    from
        SAMPLE sample0_ 
    where
        sample0_.ID=?
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException:     org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity:   [com.sample.persistence.Sample#1]
 ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "sample" does not exist
 ...
```

Obviously, this SQL statement above:

```
select
    sample0_.ID as ID0_0_,
    sample0_.TITLE as TITLE0_0_ 
from
    SAMPLE sample0_ 
where
    sample0_.ID=?
```

is not executed successfully from the PostgreSQL itself (from pgadmin).

But, if I change Sample.java to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"SAMPLE\"")
public class Sample {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "\"ID\"")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "\"TITLE\"")
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

which is weird, it works.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        sample0_."ID" as ID1_0_0_,
        sample0_."TITLE" as TITLE2_0_0_ 
    from
        "SAMPLE" sample0_ 
    where
        sample0_."ID"=?
Sample Title: Sample
```

Is hibernate.dialect useless here, or it doesn't work properly with PostgreSQL 9.1?
Also, I would like not to type columns names if they are the same as the field, but in upper case, is it also possible?

Thank you.

Comment: If you remove the hibernate dialect-related property - will it work? AFAIR the `@Entity(\""..."\")` construct is to force the JPA provider to use the exact value provided (i.e. use the exact case of the table name). Don't know why in your case it do some magic.

Comment: I tried without dialect, the original Sample.java doesn't work, modified works, also tried to use MySQL dialect instead of PostgreSQL, just to expect to see warnings or errors, the result is the same, it seems that a) dialect is ignored b) dialect is not used while constructing SQL queries, but probably only for vendor specific behavior, like pagination, for example.

Comment: and what if you would try using the JPA properties for JDBC connection (http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html#example_persistenceunit) and remove the dialect and hibernate-related properties? What's the exact table name in your DB?

Comment: PostgreSQL script:

_CREATE TABLE "SAMPLE"
(
  "ID" integer NOT NULL,
  "TITLE" character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "SAMPLE_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID" )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "SAMPLE"
  OWNER TO postgres;_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Table("\"...\"")` construct is to force the JPA provider to use the exact value you provide (i.e. use the exact case of the table name).

Moreover, it's similar in the PostgreSQL world. If you invoke `CREATE TABLE` and specify the table name in quotes than it will create the table with the exact name you specify (not only the case but also the semantics - in this way you can even create a table named TABLE):

```
CREATE TABLE "TeSt" ( id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL )
```

will result in table **TeSt8**.

```
CREATE TABLE TeSt2 ( id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL )
```

will result in table **test2**.

Hence, to query for "TeSt" table you will need to execute `SELECT * FROM "TeSt"` (**not** `SELECT * FROM TeSt`).

So, if you create a table with `CREATE TABLE "SAMPLE"` you need to specify `@Table(name="\"SAMPLE\"")` in order to get it worked.

Comment: Added explanation to the header of my question.
Thank you.